# Convert ConfigParser.items('') to dictionary

Tags: python

How can I convert the result of a ConfigParser.items('section') to a dictionary to format a string like here:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('conf.ini')

connection_string = ("dbname='%(dbname)s' user='%(dbuser)s' host='%(host)s' "
                     "password='%(password)s' port='%(port)s'")

print connection_string % config.items('db')
```

Comment: Be careful to use _sections: this variable is not documented, so it is not guaranteed to work in future versions of python

Comment: This is valid for python 2, but if you're using python 3 you can just unpack the subscripted config into format().

  "your {pattern}".format(**config['db'])

Comment: It's as simple as `params = dict(parser['section'])`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is actually already done for you in `config._sections`.  Example:

```
$ cat test.ini
[First Section]
var = value
key = item

[Second Section]
othervar = othervalue
otherkey = otheritem
```

And then:

```
>>> from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
>>> config = ConfigParser()
>>> config.read('test.ini')
>>> config._sections
{'First Section': {'var': 'value', '__name__': 'First Section', 'key': 'item'}, 'Second Section': {'__name__': 'Second Section', 'otherkey': 'otheritem', 'othervar': 'othervalue'}}
>>> config._sections['First Section']
{'var': 'value', '__name__': 'First Section', 'key': 'item'}
```

**Edit:**  My solution to the same problem was downvoted so I'll further illustrate how my answer does the same thing without having to pass the section thru `dict()`, because `config._sections` is *provided by the module for you already*.

**Example test.ini:**

```
[db]
dbname = testdb
dbuser = test_user
host   = localhost
password = abc123
port   = 3306
```

Magic happening:

```
>>> config.read('test.ini')
['test.ini']
>>> config._sections
{'db': {'dbname': 'testdb', 'host': 'localhost', 'dbuser': 'test_user', '__name__': 'db', 'password': 'abc123', 'port': '3306'}}
>>> connection_string = "dbname='%(dbname)s' user='%(dbuser)s' host='%(host)s' password='%(password)s' port='%(port)s'"
>>> connection_string % config._sections['db']
"dbname='testdb' user='test_user' host='localhost' password='abc123' port='3306'"
```

So this solution is **not** wrong, and it actually requires one less step.  Thanks for stopping by!

Comment: This is wrong ways, since it doesn't account defaults and variables are not interpolated.

Comment: I'm not saying it is wrong, but I can't use this, because I tested it with the config parser's built in replacement %(syntax)s For the unaware this allows use of config values in other config values.  These are not expanded in the _sections member, but are via the items() function.

Comment: The answer by @jathanism is correct if and only if you don't need the defaults-and-interpolation behavior provided by `ConfigParser`.  In other words, that answer is equivalent to `ConfigParser` when its *raw* options are used; and not equivalent to the non-raw options. The follow-up ("Magic happening") comment shows how to work around the interpolation issue, but not the defaults issue.  Bottom line: config._sections works well if and only if the config file has the flat / final version of each value specified; otherwise does not.

Comment: Using _sections is dangerous. Not exposed in the API, not future proof.

Comment: This is a private API and terrible advice.

Comment: anyone following this advice is making life so much harder for maintainers of ConfigParser if they decide to change how the internals work, it makes me sad that people recommend to use private APIs

Comment: Everybody calm down. It's been six years and the API has yet to change. Now if and when the public API actually IMPROVES and is more user friendly I'll update this answer.

Comment: @jathanism the public API is harder to improve while people are mis-using `_sections` as you suggest.

Comment: The point being is that you shouldn't access these outside the module itself. It is  like private variable.

Comment: Another reason this solution is not ideal: When reading an ini file, any values under a  `[DEFAULT]` section will be missed from the `_sections` field. Michele d'Amico's solution however, will include them as expected.

Comment: What `ConfigParser`'s maintainers should do seeing this answer is provide a public api

Comment: Looks like the public API has changed. `dict(self)
 |      Return a deepcopy of self as a dictionary.
 |      
 |      All members that are ``Section`` instances are recursively turned to
 |      ordinary dictionaries - by calling their ``dict`` method.`

Comment: A word of warning to all: regardless of whether this answer or other (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28990982/7530580) approaches are used, if the sections part of the configparser is used, all the keys of sections (2nd level) will be converted to all lower case.

Comment: Any members using `_` are intended to be private. That's what the `_` means. It's for internal use only. It's not only about future-proofing the API, it's also about thread safety, and so on. You're violating the contract between yourself and the developers, if you ignore the `_` and use it anyway.

Answer (score 109):

Have you tried

```
print connection_string % dict(config.items('db'))
```

?

Comment: right. this worked for me, while the approved one somehow didn't .. maybe it's a Python version thing ..

Comment: @Ricky, I guess the user is not supposed to access _sections.

Comment: @Dacav yeah it's protected so you aren't supposed to, but it was a good contribution because it allows you to do it without dict comprehension (like this one) and maybe more people will learn about protected/private from this.

Answer (score 105):

How I did it in just one line.

```
my_config_parser_dict = {s:dict(config.items(s)) for s in config.sections()}
```

No more than other answers but when it is not the real businesses of your method and you need it just in one place use less lines and take the power of dict comprehension could be useful.

Comment: @DanielBraun: I believe James Kyle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944270/355230) is more correct.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. This provides a very pythonic solution without accessing private attributes.

Comment: The problem with using sections instead of keys is that it doesn't include the 'DEFAULT' section. you can entries that do not have a section which automatically get put into the 'DEFAULT' section. Using  `{s:dict(config.items(s)) for s in config.keys()}` seems to be safer but it really all depends on the application.

Answer (score 27):

I know this was asked a long time ago and a solution chosen, but the solution selected does not take into account defaults and variable substitution. Since it's the first hit when searching for creating dicts from parsers, thought I'd post my solution which does include default and variable substitutions by using ConfigParser.items().

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
defaults = {'kone': 'oneval', 'ktwo': 'twoval'}
parser = SafeConfigParser(defaults=defaults)
parser.set('section1', 'kone', 'new-val-one')
parser.add_section('section1')
parser.set('section1', 'kone', 'new-val-one')
parser.get('section1', 'ktwo')
parser.add_section('section2')
parser.get('section2', 'kone')
parser.set('section2', 'kthree', 'threeval')
parser.items('section2')
thedict = {}
for section in parser.sections():
    thedict[section] = {}
    for key, val in parser.items(section):
        thedict[section][key] = val
thedict
{'section2': {'ktwo': 'twoval', 'kthree': 'threeval', 'kone': 'oneval'}, 'section1': {'ktwo': 'twoval', 'kone': 'new-val-one'}}
```

A convenience function to do this might look something like:

```
def as_dict(config):
    """
    Converts a ConfigParser object into a dictionary.

    The resulting dictionary has sections as keys which point to a dict of the
    sections options as key => value pairs.
    """
    the_dict = {}
    for section in config.sections():
        the_dict[section] = {}
        for key, val in config.items(section):
            the_dict[section][key] = val
    return the_dict
```

Answer (score 15):

For an individual section, e.g. "general", you can do:

```
dict(parser['general'])
```

Comment: It is the simplest solution for reading a config-based database configuration. Which is what [I believe] Szymon Lipiński wanted to achieve.

Comment: This answer should be the correct one. Simple, correct and doesn't use protected fields

Answer (score 7):

In Python +3.6 you could do this

**file.ini**

```
[SECTION1]
one = 1
two = 2

[SECTION2]
foo = Hello
bar = World

[SECTION3]
param1 = parameter one
param2 = parameter two
```

**file.py**

```py
import configparser

cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('file.ini')
# Get one section in a dict
numbers = {k:v for k, v in cfg['SECTION1'].items()}
```

If you need all sections listed you should use `cfg.sections()`

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative would be:

**config.ini**

```
[DEFAULT]
potato=3

[foo]
foor_property=y
potato=4


[bar]
bar_property=y
```

**parser.py**

```
import configparser
from typing import Dict


def to_dict(config: configparser.ConfigParser) -> Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]:
    """
    function converts a ConfigParser structure into a nested dict
    Each section name is a first level key in the the dict, and the key values of the section
    becomes the dict in the second level
    {
        'section_name': {
            'key': 'value'
        }
    }
    :param config:  the ConfigParser with the file already loaded
    :return: a nested dict
    """
    return {section_name: dict(config[section_name]) for section_name in config.sections()}
```

**main.py**

```
import configparser

from parser import to_dict


def main():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    # By default section names are parsed to lower case, optionxform = str sets to no conversion.
    # For more information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects
    # config.optionxform = str
    config.read('config.ini')
    print(f'Config read: {to_dict(config)}')
    print(f'Defaults read: {config.defaults()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Combining Michele d'Amico and Kyle's answer (no dict),
produces a less readable but somehow compelling:

```
{i: {i[0]: i[1] for i in config.items(i)} for i in config.sections()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `Python 3.7` with `configparser` and `ast.literal_eval`:

**game.ini**

```
[assets]
tileset = {0:(32, 446, 48, 48), 
           1:(96, 446, 16, 48)}
```

**game.py**

```
import configparser
from ast import literal_eval

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('game.ini')

# convert a string to dict
tileset = literal_eval(config['assets']['tileset'])

print('tileset:', tileset)
print('type(tileset):', type(tileset))
```

**output**

```
tileset: {0: (32, 446, 48, 48), 1: (96, 446, 16, 48)}
type(tileset): <class 'dict'>
```