# Only save config if changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

Is it possible to add a check which discards a pending config change when the resulting config would be the same even tho the lines moved may have moved?

I am asking because in some scripts i save the config everytime i close some application and when i'm commiting my folder i always get stuff like [this](https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/commit/689bf5878abd024e183b74eea8bb3f78e0e5939d#diff-2db34d974a6eb54ed2b705ec31b6bf62) also i think it's unneccessary I/O load.

These are my loadCfg and saveCfg functions:

```
# I/O #
def loadCfg(path, cfg):
    """
    :param path:
    :param cfg:
    """
    if not os.path.isfile(path) or os.path.getsize(path) < 1:
        saveCfg(path, cfg)
    cfg = cfg.read(path, encoding='utf-8')

def saveCfg(path, cfg):
    """
    :param path:
    :param cfg:
    """
    with open(path, mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as cfgfile:
       cfg.write(cfgfile)
```

Comment: I presume the `cfg` objects are `configparser.ConfigParser` objects from the standard library?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Yes they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say I doubt the unnecessary I/O load matters and what you want to do is likely a case of premature optimization.

That said, here's an approach that seems to work — although I haven't tested it thoroughly or attempted to incorporated it into your `loadCfg()` and `saveCfg()` functions. (Whose names don't follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) recommended naming convention for functions, BTW).

The basic idea is to convert the initial `ConfigParser` instance into an dictionary and save it. Then, before closing the application, do that again and compare the before and after dictionaries to determine whether they're the same or not.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os


def as_dict(config):  # Utility function.
    """
    Converts a ConfigParser object into a dictionary.

    The resulting dictionary has sections as keys which point to a dict
    of the sections options as key => value pairs.

    From https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944270/355230
    """
    the_dict = {}

    for section in config.sections():
        the_dict[section] = {}
        for key, val in config.items(section):
            the_dict[section][key] = val

    return the_dict


def loadCfg(path, cfg):
    """
    :param path:
    :param cfg:
    """
    if not os.path.isfile(path) or os.path.getsize(path) < 1:
        saveCfg(path, cfg)
    cfg.read(path, encoding='utf-8')  # "read" doesn't return a value.


def saveCfg(path, cfg):
    """
    :param path:
    :param cfg:
    """
    with open(path, mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as cfgfile:
        cfg.write(cfgfile)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create a config file for testing purposes.
    test_config = ConfigParser()
    test_config.add_section('Section1')
    test_config.set('Section1', 'an_int', '15')
    test_config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'true')
    test_config.set('Section1', 'a_float', '3.1415')
    test_config.set('Section1', 'baz', 'fun')
    test_config.set('Section1', 'bar', 'Python')
    saveCfg('example.cfg', test_config)

    # Read it back in.
    config = ConfigParser()
    loadCfg('example.cfg', config)

    before_dict = as_dict(config)  # Convert it to a dict and save.

    # Change it (comment-out next line to eliminate difference).
    config.set('Section1', 'an_int', '42')

    after_dict = as_dict(config)  # Convert possibly updated contents.

    # Only update the config file if contents of configparser is now different.
    if after_dict == before_dict:
        print('configuration not changed, config file not rewritten')
    else:
        print('configuration has changed, updating config file')
        saveCfg('example.cfg', config)
```

Comment: Well, that is a premium answer and works great. Thank you very much!